# How to do atomic Read–modify–write in mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongoengine, atomic, read-write

Basically I have Post Document and `Comment` `EmbeddedDocument` as follow:

```
class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    value1 = StringField(max_length=200,)
    value2 = StringField(max_length=200,)
    value3 = StringField(max_length=200,)
    id = UUIDField(required=True, primary_key=True)

class Post(Document,):
    comments = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Comment, required=False)
```

`PUT` request may update any combination of value1, value2 and value3 for a given comment of a given post.  I use queryset `update` method to do that as follow:

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
comment = None
for comm in post.comments:
    if comm.id == comment_id:
        comment = comm

Post.objects(
    id=post_id, 
    comments__id=comment_id
).update(
        set__comments__S__value1=new_value1 or comment.value1,
        set__comments__S__value2=new_value2 or comment.value2,
        set__comments__S__value3=new_value3 or comment.value3,
)
```

But this clearly not [Read–modify–write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93modify%E2%80%93write) atomic operation. So hot Read–modify–write as one atomic operation?

Answer (score 1):

> The positional operator allows you to update list items without knowing the index position, therefore making the update a single atomic operation.

The positional operator (set__comments__S__value1) allows you to update exact comment, that will be selected by `comments__id=comment_id`. That means you no need cycle to get the comment. You can do everything with one operation.

> Documents may be updated atomically by using the `update_one()`,
>   `update()` and `modify()` methods on a `QuerySet` or `modify()` and `save()`
>   (with save_condition argument) on a `Document`.

Detailed [here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#atomic-updates)

Code to update only one `Comment` with given id:

```py
def put(value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
   data = {}
   if value1:
       data['set__comments__S__value1'] = value1
   if value2:
       data['set__comments__S__value2'] = value2
   if value3:
       data['set__comments__S__value3'] = value2
   Post.objects(
       id='5dab09cade20c4423a9cb4d1', 
       comments__id='18f75928-36d5-415d-b8a9-18488f954e68'
   ).update(**data)
```

Comment: this is really not an answer, I can read the comment object in other ways, this does not matter, the question was how to make atomic read-modify-write.

Comment: Transactions do exact what you want: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/client_session.html#pymongo.client_session.ClientSession.with_transaction
But it is not the best decision. 
The positional operator (set__comments__S__value1) allows you to update exact comment, that match by `comments__id=comment_id`. So, you no need find the comment separately to provide default values. I have edited my answer.